# Uploading files in Django

Tags: python, django

I have problems when uploading files in Django (1.6 version).

When I try to do **new_file_data.save()** in my views.py I get this error:

**AttributeError at /quiz/patient/22/medical_record/2/exams/**
**'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'**

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
class ComplementaryExam(models.Model):
    diagnosis = models.ForeignKey(Diagnosis, null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False)

class ExamFile (models.Model):
    exam = models.ForeignKey(ComplementaryExam, null=False)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to="documents/%Y/%m/%d")
```

**forms.py**

```
class ExamFileForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ExamFile
        fields = ['content']
```

**settings.py**

```
MEDIA_ROOT = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')]
MEDIA_ROOT_URL = '/media/'
```

**views.py**

```
def exam_create(request, patient_id, record_id, template_name="quiz/exams.html"):

    form = ComplementaryExamForm(request.POST or None)

    d = Diagnosis.objects.get(pk=record_id)
    p = Patient.objects.get(number_record=patient_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        file_form = ExamFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_complementary_exam = form.save(commit=False)
            new_complementary_exam.diagnosis = d
            new_complementary_exam.save()

            if file_form.is_valid():
                new_file_data = file_form.save(commit=False)
                new_file_data.exam = new_complementary_exam
                new_file_data.save()

            messages.success(request, 'Exame salvo com sucesso.')
            redirect_url = reverse("medical_record_new", args=(p.number_record,))
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url + "?currentTab=3")
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Não foi possível criar exame.')
    else:
        file_form = ExamFileForm(request.POST)

    return render(request, template_name, {'complementary_exam_form': form,
               'patient_id': patient_id, 'name_patient': p.name_txt,
               'record_id': record_id, 'file_form': file_form})
```

**exams.html**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Anexos</label>
            <div class="input-group  input-group-sm">
                {{ file_form.content }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT:**
This is the traceback that I got now from the webpage.

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/quiz/patient/22/medical_record/1/exams/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'quiz')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Network/Servers/macserver.numec.prp.usp.br/Users/larissamoraes/Documents/Neuromat/patientregistrationsystem/qdc/quiz/views.py" in exam_create
  616.                 new_file_data.save()
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  545.                        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  573.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _save_table
  654.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in _do_insert
  687.                                using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  232.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1514.     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  902.         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in as_sql
  860.                 for obj in self.query.objs
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in pre_save
  252.             file.save(file.name, file, save=False)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py" in save
  86.         self.name = self.storage.save(name, content)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in save
  49.         name = self._save(name, content)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py" in _save
  209.                         locks.unlock(fd)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/files/locks.py" in unlock
  59.         fcntl.lockf(fd(file), fcntl.LOCK_UN)

Exception Type: IOError at /quiz/patient/22/medical_record/1/exams/
Exception Value: [Errno 45] Operation not supported
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MEDIA_ROOT`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#media-root) should be a string, not a list.

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:
**[Errno 45] Operation not supported**

Comment: Check permissions on your target `MEDIA_ROOT` directory. If it's not that, post the full traceback and maybe I or someone else will be able to figure it out.

Comment: Hmm. That might be this bug/system dependency: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9433

Comment: Yes, the problem was this bug. Thanks, Peter.