# OSerror when uploading files over a NFS

Tags: django, macos, python-3.x, nfs

When I try to upload a media file through the django admin interface, I get this error :

```
OSError: [Errno 45] Operation not supported
```

Here is the last line of the traceback :

```
  File "/path/to/home/Envs/myenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/files/locks.py", line 112, in unlock
    ret = fcntl.lockf(_fd(f), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24764339/3156085) and one of the comments led me to [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9433) and then to [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/195420259a), introduced in the ticket as a "workaround" (see below).

Here are the change I should do in `django/core/files/locks.py` according to the workaround.

```
  elif system_type == 'posix':
     def lock(file, flags):
-        fcntl.flock(fd(file), flags)
+        fcntl.lockf(fd(file), flags)

     def unlock(file):
-        fcntl.flock(fd(file), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
+        fcntl.lockf(fd(file), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

I tried to manually reverse the changes from this commit (replacing `flock()` calls  with `lockf()` calls), but it I still get the same error.
There also are patches, but these patches seem to old (~7 years old and I use django 1.9 with python 3.5).

How could I solve this?

**EDIT :**

As plombix mentioned, my home directory is mounted on a NFS.

**EDIT2 :**

I also tried to replace the flock calls with `fcntl.fcntl()` calls and I got a different error :

```
OSError: [Errno 14] Bad address
```

Comment: dokterbob's branch [has this commit](https://github.com/dokterbob/django/commit/bbc5118190fc52e4386a530b03adf00ba7e4c306), from the comments on the issue, this simply allows passing a locking implementation. Now you need to find one that works for AFP mounts.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to specify that you are on a NFS file system ;P

lockf == flock
UNSUPORTED by NFS

cf other post in stack "[flock vs lockf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409780/flock-vs-lockf-on-linux)"

> If the semantics (behaviour over descriptor passing, forking, etc.) is acceptable, you should prefer lockf()/fcntl() locks over flock().
>
> Locks in Linux, simply because the former works on NFS etc. filesystems, whereas the latter does not.
>
> On BSDs and Mac OS X, I believe you need to explicitly use fcntl(), instead.

i suggest you redirect your operations over /temp or /goinfre/

Answer (score 0):

I'm chipping in my unconfirmed solution with Django 2.0.5. By inspecting the [`locks.py` in this version](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.0.5/django/core/files/locks.py#L99-L113), it seems that if "File locking is not supported", the `lock` and `unlock` methods will be polyfilled with "Dummy functions that don't do anything".

But attempts to get a lock on NFS system do not fall into the `except` block to be polyfilled as such. So I manually patched the `else` block to be polyfilled as well.

```
def lock(f, flags):
    # ret = fcntl.flock(_fd(f), flags)
    # return ret == 0
    return False

def unlock(f):
    # ret = fcntl.flock(_fd(f), fcntl.LOCK_UN)
    # return ret == 0
    return True
```

This is not the best solution, of course. But Django managed to do a `runserver` on my local machine, for now.